# Enable caching for lambda proxy integraion method with request body parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have an Apigateway lambda proxy POST method with request body as parameter. I enabled caching for stage and override the caching for method as well. caching working for the method, but it response back with same result even if the body parameter is changed. I tried to enable caching for request body, but couldn't see any option available on console.
[image]

Is there anyway we can add caching with request body parameter in Apigateway? Any help would be really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not that easy as you cannot use the request body as cache key. What you could try instead is to calculate a hash for your body payload and add it as http header. You can use this header to build a cache key

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html#cfn-apigateway-method-integration-cachekeyparameters

You might add `method.request.header.customheader` as key. This should work.

Caching works best with `GET` request. In case you have the option to use *queryParameters* go for this solution.

Comment: this is definitely a work around. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You put the body parameters as customer headers and use as cache parameters:

```
paths:
  /customers/{customerId}/locations/{locationId}/stuff:
    post:
      summary: List Stuff
      operationId: listStuff
      description: List Stuff
  tags:
    - Stuff
  requestBody:
    $ref: "#/components/requestBodies/ResolveServiceRequestsBody"
  parameters:
    - name: customerId
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
      description: 'Customer Id'
    - name: locationId
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
      description: 'Location Id'
  responses:
    '200':
      $ref: '#/components/responses/ListStuffResponse'
  security:
    - stuff-api-key: []
    - aws-custom-authorizer: []
    - access-token-auth: []
  x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
    type: 'aws_proxy'
    credentials:
      Fn::Sub: arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/example-${Stage}-stuff-lambda-function-role
    uri:
      Fn::Sub: 'arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${StuffFunction.Arn}/invocations'
    responses:
      default:
        statusCode: '200'
    payloadFormatVersion: '2.0'
    passthroughBehavior: 'when_no_match'
    httpMethod: 'POST'
    contentHandling: 'CONVERT_TO_TEXT'
    connectionType: 'INTERNET'
    requestParameters:
      integration.request.header.x-startDate:
        method.request.body.startDate
      integration.request.header.x-endDate:
        method.request.body.endDate
    cacheNamespace: stuff
    cacheKeyParameters:
      - method.request.path.customerId
      - method.request.path.locationId
      - integration.request.header.x-startDate
      - integration.request.header.x-endDate
```